# strange animation of iphone UI

Tags: iphone

I am making my UI from nib files and have added a few animations for UIKit.But as i continue to use my application UI starts to load while animating.Even Navigation bar show with an animation.It seems some kind of memory issue or by some reason uikit is taking time to draw its controls.Would appreciate any kind of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what i did wrong.I animated a few view using UIView animations but missed to call commitAnimation.I think this is what end up the routine.Thanks for the helps however

Answer (score 1):

You should post some code, but it sounds like you're doing view manipulations inside of a UIView animation block that you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: It depends on what you're doing, but basically, doing things that you would expect to cause immediate changes to the UI. If you do them inside an animation block instead, they will probably be animated, often in ways that were unintended.